# AWS Appsync subscriptions - "Connection failed: Connection handshake error"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am trying to make a simple subscription run on AWS amplify's appsync.

the subscription never fires and after about 30sec I get this error message when waiting for the sub in the appsync console:

```js
Error: {
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Connection failed: Connection handshake error"
        }
    ]
}
    at Object.error (https://d3owqdqy53mge.cloudfront.net/4e0034b0d516077971e58313cecbbabc76608841/main.js:135:859689)
    at d (https://d3owqdqy53mge.cloudfront.net/4e0034b0d516077971e58313cecbbabc76608841/main.js:203:1070669)
    at m (https://d3owqdqy53mge.cloudfront.net/4e0034b0d516077971e58313cecbbabc76608841/main.js:203:1071013)
    at e.value (https://d3owqdqy53mge.cloudfront.net/4e0034b0d516077971e58313cecbbabc76608841/main.js:203:1072095)
    at n.<anonymous> (https://d3owqdqy53mge.cloudfront.net/4e0034b0d516077971e58313cecbbabc76608841/main.js:135:679765)
    at r (https://d3owqdqy53mge.cloudfront.net/4e0034b0d516077971e58313cecbbabc76608841/main.js:135:675841)
    at Object.throw (https://d3owqdqy53mge.cloudfront.net/4e0034b0d516077971e58313cecbbabc76608841/main.js:135:675176)
    at s (https://d3owqdqy53mge.cloudfront.net/4e0034b0d516077971e58313cecbbabc76608841/main.js:135:674969)
```

If I recreate the call from my browser I get this error:

```js
WebSocket connection to 'wss://r23irwx4tndnjdfh7tlethffca.appsync-realtime-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/graphql?header=eyJBdXRob3JpemF0aW9uIjoiZXlKcmFXUWlPaUpTYWx3dlVEVkxOV2N5ZUd0blVXRXhWa3g2YmxVd1YwTmxZbnBsVFdsek4zZHpjelZ0Ym5SYVZrMVpUVDBpTENKaGJHY2lPaUpTVXpJMU5pSjkuZXlKemRXSWlPaUl3WldVNFlUZzVNUzB6TnpFeUxUUXhNekV0T1RsalpTMDFNelZrTTJVeE5UQmpaR0VpTENKbGRtVnVkRjlwWkNJNklqTXpZV1E0T1RneUxXUTBaalV0TkRCa09TMWlaRFl3TFdFNFpEWXlOelprTVRFellTSXNJblJ2YTJWdVgzVnpaU0k2SW1GalkyVnpjeUlzSW5OamIzQmxJam9pWVhkekxtTnZaMjVwZEc4dWMybG5ibWx1TG5WelpYSXVZV1...VSDNCYnJURTM5YmVWNEEzdW1JdGdPN0RjOVFCVkI2U09uX1ZJdVFvUElIOUZGNk10QzdtWTJLby0wQ19NTF9tSVAxdEFTVkNzSW5Zbjd4MWZzalFoUFpaS1J6MTFKbHJPdE5rOWNzOXVrd29yMU1iRGlBNklIOEJiaXIzSjNRNDlSckhXODZLM3RhQmNGSlphQVpnTEhKS05QajlBWWZhVHRNTnZnVmV4UUJhZzQ2cW5VZ3l1amF0SUMwamZ1Mk9LUUh1d2NNaGt6WjJjYlB6aWNwcG5kVk5aVVdnY1hzUlBadndFTzlENnZmZ3UyZTM0eHZXRW9mZld1RGh4LVc5Ui1HSEktbG1YTU4ydk9xd1RURTRxejdNM2Q3WGJvN3VyWUpsSHlGUUIxQSIsImhvc3QiOiJyMjNpcnd4NHRuZG5qZGZoN3RsZXRoZmZjYS5hcHBzeW5jLWFwaS51cy1lYXN0LTIuYW1hem9uYXdzLmNvbSJ9&payload=e30=' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Comment: I am getting exactly the same issue, anyone figured out why this is happening? this used to be work just fine just a few days/week ago

Comment: I getting the same error. Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found to this was to change my router...

Have no idea why it makes a difference, tried all the router setting I could think of

I used my home LTE WiFi router and kept getting this error, eventually changed to a local sim card-based router from my cell provider and it connected every time.

I have used this on many different models and works every time. The router which was failing was a Huawei B525 router, any other router doesn't give the issues...

Comment: Great find, unsettling.